# Microsoft Word: Table of Contents, multiple line header tab leader/pagination issue

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting, table-of-contents

My TOC contains three levels. At the third level, the heading is so long that there is no tab leader on the same line. The page number (which should be right aligned, as with all other headers) appears immediately after the heading, and there is no tab leader:

[Click here for Table of Contents image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTlc9.png)

I also see this with other TOC levels (not illustrated),  but only when the header only just fills one line. If I shorten the header, or indeed lengthen it, the issue does not appear. Changing the header is *not* necessarily an ideal fix!

Using Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G8030), Word for Mac version 16.14.1 (180613).

Comment: Did you modify the paragraph properties of TOC style(s) so that the Right indent is, say, 1 cm?

Comment: Brilliant – you're a star! Thank you so much!